# adding class using jquery to current target event in meteor

Tags: jquery, events, meteor

here is my code:
basically what im trying to do is , when click event is triggered add a class using jquery to the current target. instead it is throwing undefined.

```
Template.section3.events({
        "click a.th":function(e,tmp){
            console.log(e.currentTarget);
            e.currentTarget.addClass("selected");
        }
    })
```

Comment: Try to use `$(e.currentTarget).addClass("selected");`

Comment: `e.currentTarget` is the dom element, don't had the method `addClass()`

Answer (score 2):

A better pattern would be to use the `Session` variable or a ReactiveVar to keep track of the selected item, and use a helper to set the class. That way, when Meteor re-renders that part of the page due to a change in data, the class will stay.

Comment: If re-rendering is your only concern, using a reactive variable from the package `reactive-var` is more suitable than using `Session`.

Comment: I think using session would by a waste of cpu and memory usage. Am i wrong?

Comment: When Meteor updates the view to reflect the new state, it will only change the single class attribute just like the JQuery code above. Using Session to set the class name will not result in the whole template re-rendering.